# How to implement Infinite Scrolling using GAE "Cursor" and Jinja2?

Tags: python, jquery, google-app-engine, jinja2, infinite-scroll

How can I implement infinite scrolling using GAE's "cursor" feature and Jinja2?

For example, say that I retrieve all users not named John  (say, 5000 users)

## Python

```
users = User.query(User.name != "John")
user_cursor = memcache.get('user_cursor')
if user_cursor:
    users.with_cursor(start_cursor=user_cursor)
    self.render('templates/front.html', users = users)
```

And then I want to display the 5000 users, 3 at a time, and if the viewer scrolls to the bottom or clicks "Load More" the next three come up.

## HTML

```
{% for row in users | batch(3) %}
    <div class="row">
    {% for u in row %}
    <p> {{u.firstname}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    </div> 
{% endfor %}
```

What is the best (easiest) way to implement this?  Actual code would be much appreciated, I've been trying to do this for a day now, and haven't made much progress. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you want `User.query(User.name != "John")`

Answer (score 1):

Here are the missing concepts:

1) maintain a JSON object in the browser (javascript on the web page) which holds all the users fetched.

2) Also maintain a variable to store the position of the last object viewed, at the bottom of the scroll.

3) In the javascript, make a call to the backend to fetch X users.  Here is where you use the cursor to get the next X users in the query.  Append each fetch to the end of the JSON object.  You fetch

a) on page load, and then

b) every time the last object viewed is the last one in the JSON object.  (Once you get this working, you may opt to fetch a few before the browser gets to the last one.  That way, there is no delay in scrolling.)

4) Add an event listener on the page that listens for the `scroll` event.  In this function, you compare the last object viewed with the JSON object, and trigger a new fetch as needed.

Here is a helpful trick:

```
var someOffset = 400; // you may have other items on the page.

if ((yourDOM.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= window.innerHeight + someOffset) && (lastPostShown == userJSON.length)) {
    getMorePosts();
}
```

Of course, you'll need to pass the cursor back and forth between the back end of the javascript you use to fetch.

That should get you started.

Comment: If you're serving to cutting edge browsers, the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) may be useful.